# how to get a batch file to execute the next command without waiting

Tags: loops, batch-file

Im trying to write a simple batch file that will open a VLC and target a stream for load testing, id like to be able to open a number of windows, lets say 20 for now. the problem is with the script as is, it waits until the VLC program is terminated before activating another.

here is what i have:

```
@echo OFF
FOR %%x IN (0, 1, 20) DO "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" https://5e768b74d354b.streamlock.net/tcproedge/ahowardtestingGenesis/MP4:ahowardtestingGenesis/IKqUJhTfIe4uQA8LbLA5high/playlist.m3u8
PAUSE
```

is there a way to get the for loop execute the next command regardless if the previous has terminated? or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with your `FOR` command is not correct. Currently it will perform three loops, one for each string token, *identified using one or more concurrent delimiters*. The most common of those are <kbd>SP</kbd> *(space)*, <kbd>HT</kbd> *(horizontal tab)*, <kbd>,</kbd> *(comma)*, <kbd>;</kbd> *(semi-colon)*, <kbd>=</kbd> *(equal sign)*, and <kbd>LF</kbd> *(line feed)*. In your case the concurrent comma and space provide just three tokens: `0`, `1` and `20`.

What you needed was to run twenty loops, and you can do that by using the `FOR /L` method. This method will loop beginning at the first integer, incrementing by the second integer, and ending at the third integer.

To better understand how the `FOR` command works, please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>/<kbd>⏎</kbd>/<kbd>RETURN</kbd> key.

As for your main issue, when you run an executable file from a batch file or cmd.exe, control is not passed to the next command until that process has completed. In order to bypass that restriction, you can use the `START` command, which will essentially run the command `Start`, with the executable file as an argument, and complete *(irrespective of what that executable does)*.

To better understand how the `START` command works, please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>/<kbd>⏎</kbd>/<kbd>RETURN</kbd> key.

One important thing to be aware of with `Start`, is, should your arguments be double-quoted, *which I recommend as best practice, regardless of whether it includes spaces*, the first double-quoted string is seen by `Start` as the 'title', so you should include a title, even an empty one, `""`, to prevent your application becoming the title and the URI string as executable.

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example:

```sh
@For /L %%G In (1, 1, 20) DO @Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "https://5e768b74d354b.streamlock.net/tcproedge/ahowardtestingGenesis/MP4:ahowardtestingGenesis/IKqUJhTfIe4uQA8LbLA5high/playlist.m3u8"
```

You will also note here, that I double-quoted the argument to `VLC.exe`, also as a best practice, to protect any potential poison characters.